# The value in one column depends in the value of another column

Tags: r

I want to make all rows with number 2 in column q1 to zero in column q2. Anyone have a smart solution?

```
a <- rep(c(300,450), each=c(3,3))
q1 <- rep(c(1,1,2,1,1,2),2)
q2 <- c(100,40,"",80,30,"" , 45,78,"",20,58,"")

df <- cbind(a,q1,q2)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
```

Original input data :

```
> df
     a q1  q2
1  300  1 100
2  300  1  40
3  300  2    
4  450  1  80
5  450  1  30
6  450  2    
7  300  1  45
8  300  1  78
9  300  2    
10 450  1  20
11 450  1  58
12 450  2
```

Desired output :

```
> df
     a q1  q2
1  300  1 100
2  300  1  40
3  300  2  0  
4  450  1  80
5  450  1  30
6  450  2  0  
7  300  1  45
8  300  1  78
9  300  2  0  
10 450  1  20
11 450  1  58
12 450  2  0
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would  be to create a logical vector based on the column 'q1' and assign the value of 'q2' to 0

```
df$q2[df$q1 == 2] <- 0
df
#     a q1  q2
#1  300  1 100
#2  300  1  40
#3  300  2   0
#4  450  1  80
#5  450  1  30
#6  450  2   0
#7  300  1  45
#8  300  1  78
#9  300  2   0
#10 450  1  20
#11 450  1  58
#12 450  2   0
```

---

Another option is `replace`

```
transform(df, q2 = replace(q2, q1 == 2, 0))
```

With `cbind`, it converts to a `matrix` first, so any character element anywhere results in the whole `matrix` to be `character`.  Better, would be use `data.frame` directly

---

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[q1== 2, q2 := '0']
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(a, q1, q2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```